# unable to get selected spinner value when assign values from strings.xml in android application

Tags: java, android, xml

In `android application` to `populate values` into `spinner` I have `used values from  values\strings.xml`

```
 <string-array name="myList">
       <item>first</item>
        <item>second</item>
  </string-array>
```

In `layout\input_box.xml`

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_problems"
        android:entries="@array/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
         />
```

above code will `populate spinner values from myList`

on `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  spin_problem = (Spinner)findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));   
        spin_problem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view1, int pos, long id)
             {
                  spin_problem_val= adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
             }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    //thread run
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    showInputDialog("Any Complaints?");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }}, 8000);  // 3000 milliseconds
        //end thread        

}
```

showInputDailog method code
// my textbox and spinner is in this method

```
public void showInputDialog(final String textparam) throws JSONException {      
         try{
        // get prompts.xml view to show complaint popup 
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
         if(textparam.toString() == "Feedback"){alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Feedback");}
         else{alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Any Complaints?");}

        //Get all dialog box values
        final EditText name = (EditText) promptView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText mobno = (EditText) promptView
                .findViewById(R.id.mobno);
        final EditText complaint = (EditText) promptView
                .findViewById(R.id.complaint);



        // final Spinner problems = (Spinner)findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));     
        // final Spinner area = (Spinner)findViewById((R.id.spinner_area));

    //  final String aa = problems.getSelectedItem().toString();
     // final String vvv = area.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

//HERE I need to get spinner value to process further... 
}

Comment: did you add `onItemSelectedListener` to your spinner?

Comment: no whats that ? is it necessary ? i'm pretty new to android development .. can you help me in this ?

Comment: Did you set the spinner adapter?

Comment: No I did not... I only write above code .. and I can see values (first,second) in spinner dropdown.
now I want to select those values which is selected by user and do operation on that value for example save into database 
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get values from spinner, add `onItemSelectedListener` to your spinner. Like this :

```
     String value;
     final Spinner problems = (Spinner)findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
      problems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view1, int pos, long id)
         {
              value= adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
         }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Edit :

-For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652414/how-do-you-get-the-selected-value-of-a-spinner), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399086/how-to-use-spinner), and [this](http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105).

Edit 2 :

- if your spinner is in your main_activity, add the code inside your onCreate method with `value` as global variable.
- if you want your spinner in an alertDialog, add the code inside your showInputDialog method

Comment: thanks I able to resolve it by following code 
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
  View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
 final Spinner problems = (Spinner) promptView.findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
   spin_problem_val = problems.getSelectedItem().toString();