# prevent spinner,s OnItemSelectedListner being fired on startup

Tags: android, spinner

Does anybody have any idea on how to prevent a spinners `OnItemSelectedListener` being fired at start up? It should be fired when someone clicks on it and chooses a specific item from the list. Please help if anybody knows this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/android-how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be able to help [Android Spinner selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636098/android-spinner-selection/2649198#2649198)