# Android Spinner OnItemChange Vs OnItemSelect events

Tags: android, event-handling, spinner

In Android Spinner, I can set selection to a particular Item in the code (using setSelection(int)). This will end up calling OnItemSelectedListener, which is fine.

But when the user selects an item from the screen, by clicking the spinner and the item, I want to handle this as a different event, because the logic in my application should do different things.

How to achieve this?
To summarize, My Spinner should do this

```
If Value set from the code {
//do this..
}
else if user select a value {
//do that..
}
```

Comment: So I am expecting something like OnItemChange. I tried using OnItemClick, LongClick etc.. which just threw runtimeException.

Comment: You're expecting different functionality than the spinner provides. You're free to write your own spinner class though.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15675409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `Spinner` and override `setSelection(int)`. Insert functionality you want to happen in this case and then call `super.setSelection(int)` to keep the Spinner working normally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still this will end up calling onItemSelected method, which has a logic to perform when user selects from the screen. So I need a way to know in onItemSelected method that this was set in the code or set by the user.

Comment: So you have different code that executes in each case? Just move one of the code to .setSelection().

Comment: Hack: or change the `int` in `setSelection(int)` to `int + 10000` and you will know that this came from code. Not sure if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a global variable to indicate me who is calling the  onItemSelected method. Looks like solved my purpose. But any better solutions are welcome.

Comment: +1 This modus operandi is an unsung hero for ~90% of all coding problems.