# Spinner OnclickListener event executes twice, how to handle both events

Tags: android, spinner

Spinner OnclickListener event executes twice -

- Spinner initialization
- User selected manually

where as implementation of listener is as :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {           
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

***Problem definition***

I want to save user selected text into data storage, when user choose any item from spinner, and I am able to do this. But my another task is that to show previously selected item (access from data storage) as selected item in spinner, but each time when I call spinner's activity, spinner shows first item as default selected item, and also in data storage it make change previous item to default.

How can I make difference between  'Spinner initialization' and 'User selected manually' events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You have to handle both events logically. As these references ([Android Spinner selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636098/android-spinner-selection/2649198#2649198), [problem on spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/android-how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinn)) says that you have to use flag variable to handle this, I am putting a code sample.*

*Hope this will help you to clear your logic.*

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {  

    //Checks report spinner selection is default or user selected item
    private boolean isDefaultSelection;
    //Spinner setup
    Spinner spinner;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        // Set true at onCreate
        isDefaultSelection = true;

         spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_of_spinner);      
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.drop_down_custom_row, data);
        //Implement custom view for drop down of spinner
        //spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {          
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(isDefaultSelection) { //If spinner initializes
                    spinner.setSelection("Set_here_id_of_data_item_from_storage_which_was_previously_stored");
                    isDefaultSelection = false;
                } else { //If user manually select item
                    int itemPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    //Write here code to store selection (itemPosition) of user into data storage
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //User selected same item. Nothing to do.
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Hope it will clear your doubt.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the `setSelection` at the same time that the items are added to the adapter, see this example: [How to avoid onItemSelected to be called twice in Spinners](http://knewless.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/android-how-to-avoid-onitemselected-to.html)