# How to start activity on item selected?

Tags: android, android-activity, drop-down-menu, menu, items

I created a drop-down menu and i overrided the onItemSelected method:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

With the above code if i select an item then it shows a toast with selected item.
I tried to edit the code in this way:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Selection.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Why it doesn't allow me to select an item and go to MainActivity instead?

Comment: it looks good. Do you get errors?

Comment: It shows me toast with first item and appear MainActivity without showing Selection activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slm;according to the docs :

"*Spinners provide a quick way to select one value from a set.In the 
**default state**, a spinner shows its **currently selected value**. Touching the spinner displays 
a dropdown menu with all other available values, from which the user can select a new one.*"

so it's normal to trigger the callback on the first item shown in your list and implement

it;;you  can handle that by ignoring the first callback and put the first item shown in two

different positions.OR see more in this link " [How to keep onItemSelected from firing off on a newly instantiated Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinner?rq=1) ".