# Spinner is opened when try to select an item in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/DateOfBirthMM"
                                android:layout_width="90dp"
                                android:layout_height="60dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/new_con_txt_back"
                                android:ems="25"
                                android:minWidth="90dp"
                                android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

in String file

```
  <string-array name="month_array">
        <item>MMM</item>
        <item>Jan</item>
        <item>Feb</item>
        <item>Mar</item>
        <item>Apr</item>
        <item>May</item>
        <item>Jun</item>
        <item>Jul</item>
        <item>Aug</item>
        <item>Sep</item>
        <item>Oct</item>
        <item>Nov</item>
        <item>Dec</item>
    </string-array>
```

and spinner_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"

    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

And in activity file

```
DateOfBirthMM = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.DateOfBirthMM);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(OtherNewActivity.this, R.array.month_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        DateOfBirthMM.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in the edit method i am trying to preload the month in the spinner.

```
int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(compareValue.trim());

                DateOfBirthMM.setSelection(spinnerPosition);

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
```

when the edit acitvity is loaded i get the spinner dialog opened!! like if i have done performClick!!! what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with set selection method. When you call setSelection, all listeners all called after you method executions.

You can find several fixes/aproaches to get it done in this question

[How to keep onItemSelected from firing off on a newly instantiated Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinner)

I hope this would help you!