# Changing value of textview using android spinners

Tags: android, listview, textview, spinner

I have a spinner(dynamic) which contains a list of IDs' and each ID has a product value. When I click on a particular ID, the value needs to be changed associated with that ID.

I have a listView which contains a table. The table consists of product names, product price and product information. When I change the ID, the table information(listview) changes but not the product value (this is a textview and not part of listview).

I'm passing the product value using an intent from a different class. How do I make it such that when I change an item in the spinner, the product value gets changed?

```
 /**
     * Listener for flight leg selection of spinner
     */
    private OnItemSelectedListener onFlightLegSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            new ShowSalesReportAsyncTask(flightLegMap.get(flightLegs.get(position)), position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    };
```

This is my onCreate where I am getting the product value.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_report);
        salesReportListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sales_report_listview);
        spinnerFlightLegs = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.flight_legs);
        noTransactionsWarning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_transactions_warning);
        totalValueNetAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_currency_net_value);
        String salesRevenue = TOTAL_VALUE;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            salesRevenue = extras.getString(TOTAL_VALUE);
        }
        totalValueNetAmount.setText(salesRevenue);



        flightLegMap = getAllFlightLegs();
        if (!flightLegMap.isEmpty()) {
            setFlightLegSpinner();
            btnShare.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btnShare.setEnabled(false);
        }

        spinnerFlightLegs.setOnItemSelectedListener(onFlightLegSelectedListener);
        salesReportListAdapter = new SalesReportListAdapter(this);
        salesReportListView.setAdapter(salesReportListAdapter);
```

This is the Async task that I use to populate the view with data.

private class ShowSalesReportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask> {

```
private String flightLeg;
private int position;

public ShowSalesReportAsyncTask(String flightLeg, int position) {
    this.flightLeg = flightLeg;
    this.position = position;
}

@Override
protected List<Purchase> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    List<Purchase> rows = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
    PurchaseDao purchaseDao = new PurchaseDao(flightLeg, MIUtils.getShardDatabaseIndexMap());
    LOG.debug(TAG + "Getting report for : {}", flightLeg);
   // double netTotal = SalesUtil.calculateFlightTransactionTotal(purchaseDao, refundDao,());
    return purchaseDao.getSuccessfulTransactions();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Purchase> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        noTransactionsWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        noTransactionsWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    salesReportListAdapter.setRowsAndFlightDetails(result, flightLegMap.get(flightLegs.get(position)),
            spinnerFlightLegs.getSelectedItem().toString());

     totalValueNetAmount.setText((int) netTotal);

}
```

}

The item that needs to be changed is "EUR". [SPINNER TABLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRyBO.png)

Comment: What is product value ? EUR 98.00 ?

Comment: Did you print/log the value ? What does it print ? Null or blank ?

Comment: product value is EUR 98.00. When I change the spinner, it should show a new product value but instead, it shows 98.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code to register the listener in the onStart() method of the activity. This should work.

This should better answer your question - [How to keep onItemSelected from firing off on a newly instantiated Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinner)