# How I can store the spinner's selected item, and use it in an another class?

Tags: android

I have a settings class. In this class I have a spinner, with 4 number. I want to use these numbers, in an another class to modify the program"s run. If the 3 is selected I want to be the thread for 3 sec, if 5 for 5 sec ...
How can I store the spinner's position and use it in the another class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about implementing an onItemSelected event for your Spinner? [Like the get the selected item changed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event)

Inside this event you can edit and store your value in the [Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

This will let you share your spinner actual value across all your activities/classes. Where you can get the value throught the dictionary.

Ask me if you don't understand.