# A spinner controlling another spinner

Tags: java, android, event-handling, spinner, listener

[image]

No but in all seriousness, What i'm trying to do is make it so that the selection made by the user in the first spinner dictates the options available in the second.

I'm a little confused as to how to handle this. I'm thinking it would require some sort of listener since the selections could be changed at any time.

As an example lets say I had 2 spinners, the first has options "even numbers" and "odd numbers". If the user selects even numbers the second spinner displays options "2", "4", and "6". If the user selects odd numbers "1", "3", and "5" are selected.

Comment: You made me lol at the first sight of your post! Nice one :)

Comment: What a JOKE!!! Can you please remove your picture plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you need to assign a listener for the first spinner in you example. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event) thread to check how to do that. In the onItemSelected() callback, you need to modify the contents of the second spinner accordingly. That is, modify the adapter assigned to it.