# How to Change Layout and Field of AlertDialog Dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have One Spinner in AlertDialog. 
On First look their will be only on spinner, and three options in it:

1. Add Text Area,
2. Add Edit Text,
3. Add Radio Button.

WHen user will select any one option in the sipnner, AlerDialog should disply Text Area/Edit Text/Radio in the AlertDialog under the Spinner.

Any help/links

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the XML Layout view with your spinner and the text, edit text, and radio button.  You Set the visibility of your text, edit text, and radio button to GONE.

I think the easiest way to do this is to extend the AlertDialog object.  In the object you can set the view of you AlertDialog using

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
```

Now you can get references to your elements using

```
(EditText) editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTextIdOnLayout);
```

Add a listener to you spinner and based on the options that is chose you can now use your element handles to change the visibility of what you want to show.

Comment: Hi, I have try and mostly done, but onClick of Spinner is not working,
How can i refresh alertDialog when spinner seletion changed.

Comment: I'm sure that the spinners view is refreshed by the spinner object.  You should be adding the spinners events in the alertdialog object's constructor or a method that is guaranteed to be run.  At that point you should be handling the spinner how u normally do.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with spinners as i don't use them much but I think you want to use the onItemselectedListener().  Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event

Comment: When an item is selected you can change the visibly of your elements.

Comment: Ahan, Great, Thanks jjNford.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Create Layout what you want and set it `alertDialog.setContenView(R.layout.alertdialg);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a layout with Text, Radio and etc. Set the property Visibility = GONE for them. After selecting a value from spinner, set the required fields property Visibility = VISIBLE.