# Add second spinner in same activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm doing one project in Android and I want to add a second spinner in the same activity. It should be independent of first spinner.

How can I do it?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line;
import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView myText= (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this,"You have Selected "+ myText.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }



}
```

What needs to be done next?

Comment: you can handle it with only one listener override methods.. Check answer i just published

Comment: if you got the answer valuable then you can mark correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Create another spinner say `spinner2`

Then just repeat your code:

```
 spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
 ArrayAdapter adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Dont forget to create **another spinner** i.e. spinner2 in your **.xml** as well.

The complete code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
        Spinner spinner,spinner2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,     R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


             spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
             ArrayAdapter adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });


    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View     selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });

     }

    }
```

Comment: oh thanks!!should have i to add those two override methods of spinner?

Comment: then just omit spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);/ spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); and use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event

Comment: //now i have done this// spinner2.OnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView myText1= (TextView) view;
            Toast.makeText(this,"You have Selected "+ myText1.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


    });but i m getting error for OnItemSelectedListener,parent,view what should i do now?

Comment: Import it..i mean you have to import OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: and if you go for the above approach then rempve the interface i.e. " implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener "

Comment: sorry but i can't be able to understAnd what u r trying to say!

Comment: If you want to follow the approach provided in the lick then you must remove the interface which you have written in the first line i.e. implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: i have removed  i.e. implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener but i m getting same errors

Comment: which one?yes i have already checked one by removing  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener!!

Comment: okay thanx!!! i have done that now errors r reduced and now i m getting error "Error:(32, 47) error: cannot find symbol class OnItemSelectedListener" for both OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: now just import 
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: okay tysm!! sry for disturbing but now i m getting this error "Error:(37, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable view"

Comment: Oh...you have to import each and every thing showing this error.

Comment: i have already imported view library, look i havre imported these ones//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

Answer (score 1):

Add another Spinner to your XML and same ways declare and initialise it .

```
Spinner spinner1 , spinner2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.field_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner2_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        }
```

You don't need to override separate methods for each spinner in same layout.following will work for both spinner1 and spinner2 . you can implement check to get to know item of which spinner is selected

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parentView;
     if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1){
               //do this                
        }
     else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2){
              //do this
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // your code here
  }
```

Remember that for one spinner, OnItemSelectedListener event will execute twice -

1. Spinner initialization
2. User selected any item manually

You can differentiate those two by using flag variable.