# Which event is called when user exits spinner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a spinner and I want to show/hide something when the user exits the spinner without doing any thing. for example, when the user touches an area outside the spinner.
p.s. the onTouchEvent for the container layout (LinearLayout in my case) is also not called.
here is my implementation for the custom spineer:

```
public SpinnerHintAdapter(Activity context, int resourceId, int textViewId, List<SpinnerItem> list, Spinner parent){

    super(context,resourceId,textViewId, list);
    flater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    this.items = list;
    this.gender = parent;

}

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return items.size();
 }

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public SpinnerItem getItem(int position) {
     return items.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     SpinnerItem spinnerItem = getItem(position);
     View rowView = flater.inflate(R.layout.gender_item ,null,true);
     TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
     txtTitle.setText(spinnerItem.getName());
     txtTitle.setTextColor(txtTitle.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
     Log.i(Tags.byEmail, "VVVVVVVVVVVVv");;
     gender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     return rowView;
}


 @Override
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     firstTime = false;
     SpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
     View rowView = flater.inflate(R.layout.gender_drop_down_item ,null,true);
     TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drop_down_text);
     txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getName());
     if(!isEnabled(position)){
         txtTitle.setBackground(txtTitle.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_rounded_text_field));
         txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#777777"));
     }
     parent.setBackground(parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal_rounded_text_field));
     txtTitle.setEnabled(isEnabled(position));
     gender.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     Log.i(Tags.byEmail, "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
     return rowView;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
     if(position == 0)
         return false;
     return super.isEnabled(position);
 }
```

}

when the user exits without selecting an item the getView function is not called and hence the gender (is the spinner object itself) will not be visible.
I tried OnItemSelected and OnNothingSelected are also not called.
event OnTouch events are not called.

The following Events are not called when the user exits:
1- OnItemSlected 
2- OnNothingSelected
3- OnFocusChanged.
4- OnTouch

Comment: `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected`?

Comment: Provided code will help.

Comment: may helps this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714426/3790150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's event will work for you as magic, no?

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {

    ... Constructors ...

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        Log.d(CustomSpinner.class.getSimpleName(), "onWindowFocusChanged: " + hasWindowFocus);
        if (hasWindowFocus) {
            // User click out of window
        } else {
            // User click in spinner window
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first attempt. It is only called when someone selects an item.. the case here is : the user exists before selecting anything

Comment: @alnourahmed "the user exists before selecting anything" what do mean saing "user exists" and what moment of time or event you whant to catch?

Comment: I think onNothingSelected is called when user click on spinner and dropdown menu appears but user click outside the dropdown

Comment: @KamranAhmedKhan, No I tested this scenario. Unfortunately it is not called.

Comment: @alnourahmed I change example and create custom spinner to check how it will works with onWindowFocusChanged() and it's works fine!

Answer (score 0):

With a `Spinner` you set an `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` which implements two methods; `onItemSelected` and `onNothingSelected`.

Like this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // This is called when the user selects an item in the Spinner
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // This is called when the user closes the spinner selecting nothing
    }
});
```