# When click on Android spinner the item cannot be chosen

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, spinner

Could you please help me? The spinner I have created a spinner. When I click on it I can see a list of items but when I click on any of them, the drop-down many closes, and no element gets selected.
I tried to change text color, and background but nothing helps. Any idea what could be a problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

int quantity = 0;
TextView textView;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayList spinnerArraylist;
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter;
HashMap goodsMap;
String goodsname;
double price;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerArraylist = new ArrayList();

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArraylist);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


    spinnerArraylist.add("guitar");
    spinnerArraylist.add("drums");
    spinnerArraylist.add("keybord");

    goodsMap = new HashMap();
    goodsMap.put("guitar", 500.0);
    goodsMap.put("drums", 1500.0);
    goodsMap.put("keybord", 1000.0);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    goodsname = spinner.getTransitionName().toString();
    price = (double) goodsMap.get(goodsname);
    TextView priceTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    priceTextView.setText("" + quantity + price);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

The spinner itself:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:theme="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dropdown</item>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Spinner: Get the selected item change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event)

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Comment: Actually it is. Read it carefully and compare with your code.